# complete command's parameters with oh-my-zsh

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh, tab-completion

Is there a way to make zsh complete parameters of commands (just like the fish shell do). For example, when I type `ls --` and use TAB it will pop up a list of all `ls` parameters.

I know that I can use fish shell for this, and I know that fish shell is amazing, but there is a lot of missing functionalities in the fish shell. That's why I am looking to bring this parameter completion in zsh.

Comment: I'm pretty sure oh-my-zsh does this out of the box, on my version I can press tab twice on `ls --` and get the full list of parameters. For even more completions, check https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-completions

Comment: It works for ls, but not for all the available commands.

Comment: Neither fish or zsh (oh-my-zsh in this case) have autocompletion automatically "parsed" from the command, you have to define the autocompletions by yourself or import a configuration. There is a tutorial on how to write your completions here: https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-completions/blob/master/zsh-completions-howto.org

Comment: In fish, you just have to run the command `fish_update_completions` and then it will pop up a parameter completion for almost every command.

Answer (score 7):

Try with single hyphen, like `ls -`. All built in commands are working fine. Btw for custom oh-my-zsh plugin autocompletion, it depends on plugin configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the answer bro. I know that the autocompletion works fine with the default built in commands, but that's not the same for the newer installed commands. I am looking for a behavior like the fish shell, it parse all the commands manual pages, and give an autocompletion for almost every available command in the system.

Comment: Every shell has their advantages and disadvantages. It's the strongest advantages of fish-shell. Try oh-my-zsh plugins. There are very big collections. Most of the plugins support that autocomplete. If you don't find your desired one, then why not make your own plugin.

Comment: Which oh my ash plugin provides autocompletion ??!!

Comment: There is a plugin for every populer command. You will find all the plugins here: https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/Plugins

Comment: It's true that there is a lot of plugins for completion, but the one I need are not available (like aircrack-ng, msfvenom).

Answer (score 2):

oh-my-zsh has over 200 plugins for different commands. But unfortunately the auto completions are all hand made. So there will be never auto complete function for every command.

Comment: There will never be a plugin that parse manual pages ?? is it impossible due to zsh architecture or what ??!!

Comment: The problem is not zsh. The problem is the content of the man pages. Sometimes the parameters under DESCRIPTION section, sometimes under the OPTIONS section. The next Problem are dynamic parameters like a branch Name in git.

Comment: But fish shell succeeded providing this functionality.

Comment: Fish has a hard-coded list with commands to ignore. For example the can not parse the man page from wget

Comment: @DanielKäfer so could this also be implemented in zsh?